# Apple external display webcam not functioning with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, lenovo, webcam, camera, apple

I am currently having issues getting the webcam on my Apple thunderbolt display to be detected. My setup is as follows:

Software: Ubuntu 20.04 with kernel 5.4.0-52-generic.

Hardware: Lenovo X1 carbon gen 7, Apple thunderbolt 3 to thunderbolt 2 adapter, Apple thunderbolt display(with webcam)

Upon booting up my laptop with my Apple display connected, I am only able to see my laptop's integrated webcam but not the webcam from my external display. The terminal command `v4l2-ctl --list-devices` outputs:

```
Integrated Camera: Integrated C (usb-0000:00:14.0-8):
    /dev/video0
    /dev/video1
```

If I physically disconnect/reconnect my thunderbolt 3 from my laptop, however, and repeat the command `v4l2-ctl --list-devices`, I see the output:

```
Integrated Camera: Integrated C (usb-0000:00:14.0-8):
    /dev/video0
    /dev/video1

FaceTime HD Camera (Display): F (usb-0000:32:00.2-1.5):
    /dev/video2
    /dev/video3
```

So, my Apple display webcam is now detected and functions with apps such as Skype. I've taken a look at what driver each webcam is using via the command `ls -ld /sys/class/video4linux/video0/device/driver`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 31 21:10 /sys/class/video4linux/video1/device/driver -> ../../../../../../bus/usb/drivers/uvcvideo
```

and `ls -ld /sys/class/video4linux/video2/device/driver`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 31 21:52 /sys/class/video4linux/video2/device/driver -> ../../../../../../../../../../../../../../bus/usb/drivers/uvcvideo
```

So it looks like they're both using the uvcvideo driver. I've tried to remove and add the uvcvideo driver via: `modprobe -r uvcvideo && modprobe uvcvideo` with no luck. I've also installed the facetimehd driver from here (the driver installs without error): https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie, but the same symptoms persist.

Any ideas how I can get my system to recognize my Apple display webcam without having to physically disconnect/reconnect my external display?

Thanks for your help!

**UPDATE**

I ran the command `lsusb -t` with the following outputs:

1. Upon bootup of my laptop:

```
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 10000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 9: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 12M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/2p, 12M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/2p, 12M
```

2. After physically disconnecting my external display:

```
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 10000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 9: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 12M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
```

3. After physically reconnecting my external display:

```
/:  Bus 05.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/7p, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 5, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 5, If 3, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
        |__ Port 5: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 5: Dev 3, If 2, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 480M
        |__ Port 5: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 7: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 10000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 9: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 12M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/2p, 12M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/2p, 12M
```